# Codeigniter - make library run automatically

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a lib like so

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Iadmin {

    function check()
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->helper('url');
        $CI->load->helper('cookie');
        if(!get_cookie('lemon')){
            redirect('http://www.google.com/'); 
        }
    }
}

?>
```

In the autoload.php I have

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('iadmin');
```

What I want to do: If I don't have cookie "lemon", I will be redirect to google when I try to access any page of my website

Problem: I'm not getting redirected to google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could extend the default controller with MY_Controller and then extend that in all your controllers.

In application/libraries/MY_Controller.php

```
<?php
    class MY_Controller extends Controller {
        function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();

            $this->load->helper('url');
            $this->load->helper('cookie');
            if(!get_cookie('lemon')){
                redirect('http://www.google.com/'); 
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

in application/controllers/home.php

```
<?php   
    class Home extends MY_Controller {
        function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
        }

        function index(){
            // Index page
        }
    }
?>
```

Going to www.site.com/index.php/home would redirect you if you didn't have the lemon cookie.

You may also be able to do something like this with a hook, I'm not sure though as I've never used them.

Comment: This is how I would go about it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Hooks in this situation, rather than libraries. Create a hook that runs before any of your controllers are loaded, and put your code to check for the cookie in the hook constructor.

Reference: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html

Answer (score 0):

After adding the class in library you need to call the function Check() to make it execute or place that code in constructor.

Comment: thanks but I'm looking for a solution not having to call the check() in EVERY CONTROLLERS.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just put that code in the `Iadmin` class' constructor? That should fix your problem, the `check` method doesn't get called automatically.